# Error: Missing required provider in next stage even after init

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have following CI configurations:

```
...
cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  paths:
    - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform


before_script:
  - echo -e "credentials \"$CI_SERVER_HOST\" {\n  token = \"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"\n}" > $TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE
  - cd ${TF_ROOT}
  - export TF_LOG_CORE=TRACE
  - export TF_LOG_PATH=terraform_logs.txt

stages:
  - initialize
  - validate
  
init:
  stage: initialize
  script:
    - terraform -v
    - terraform init 
    #- terraform validate
    
validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

My `init` runs totally fine however i get following in the next stage i.e. `validate`:

```
$ terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Missing required provider
│ 
│ This configuration requires provider registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog,
│ but that provider isn't available. You may be able to install it
│ automatically by running:
│   terraform init
```

in `provider.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14"
  required_providers {
    datadog = {
      source  = "DataDog/datadog"
      version = "2.24.0"
    }
  }
}
```

in `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "some rummer"
  url = "****
  token = "***"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

If run the validate as subsequent command in the `init` stage itself if works fine, but just not in the different stage.

If i do `ls -al` in the next stage before `validate`, i can even see `.terraform` folder present which should be having providers inside?

Second guess was a caching issue, however I believe I have specified caches correctly `- ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform`?

I am running the `gitlab-runner` as `shell` executor.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a `required_providers` section anywhere in your code?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, update question with `provider.tf`

Comment: Are you using modules? If so, you might need to declare a similar block in all of them. I remember having a similar issue with MongoDB provider.

Comment: it is all modules, contains and similar provider block.

Comment: Does the state persist over different stages, i.e., is `validate` stage aware of what happened in `init`?

Comment: What is the GitlabCI agent for this CI configuration (per stage or global)?

Comment: @MarkoE i believe so yes, since `.terraform` directory created during `init` stage is available during `validate` stage also. or is there any other way i can confirm this?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Not sure, i have added `config.toml` details in question also. Or if i should look for above information elsewhere?